# How do we count rows using JOOQ?

Tags: java, count, jooq

We have a table in database called Books, how can we count total number of book records with [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int count = 
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectCount()
   .from(Books)
   .fetchOne(0, int.class);
```

All the best!